# problems with dependency and apt-get

Tags: apt

I am trying to fix some dependencies (python) via

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

and it asks me to try the command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

and I got te following which I don't know what to do with them:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 454 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/71.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 578, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 524, in get_config_vars
_init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 408, in _init_posix
from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
from _sysconfigdata_nd import *
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit        status 1
dpkg: error processing package libgksu2-0 (--configure):
package libgksu2-0 is not ready for configuration
cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gksu:
gksu depends on libgksu2-0 (>= 2.0.8); however:
Package libgksu2-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package gksu (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-pyinotify (0.9.4-1build1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a       followup error from a previous failure.
                      Could not find platform dependent libraries     <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 563, in <module>
main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 545, in main
known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 272, in addusersitepackages
user_site = getusersitepackages()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 247, in getusersitepackages
user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 237, in getuserbase
USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 578, in get_config_var
return get_config_vars().get(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 524, in get_config_vars
_init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 408, in _init_posix
from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
from _sysconfigdata_nd import *
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
dpkg: error processing package python-pyinotify (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg:         dependency problems prevent configuration of grive-tools:
grive-tools depends on python-pyinotify; however:
Package python-pyinotify is not configured yet.
grive-tools depends on gksu; however:
Package gksu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grive-tools (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Errors were   encountered while processing:
gconf2
libgksu2-0
gksu
python-pyinotify
grive-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I execute the command

`lsb_release -a`
I get the following:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

`uname -a`

```
Linux abdulla-VGN-CS230J 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12   11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`apt-cache policy libgksu2-0`

```
libgksu2-0:
Installed: 2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4
Candidate: 2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4
Version table:
*** 2.0.13~pre1-6ubuntu4 0
    500 http://bh.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64    Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

After repairing the Python package and trying again `sudo apt-get -f install` I got the following error

```
dpkg: error processing package libgksu2-0 (--configure):
 package libgksu2-0 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status `half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gksu:
 gksu depends on libgksu2-0 (>= 2.0.8); however:
  Package libgksu2-0 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package gksu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python-pyinotify (0.9.4-1build1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grive-tools:
 grive-tools depends on gksu; however:
  Package gksu is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package grive-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Setting up python2.7-minimal (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up python2.7 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2) ...
Setting up libpython2.7:amd64 (2.7.6-8ubuntu0.2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgksu2-0
 gksu
 grive-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running `sudo dpkg --configure -a` gives the following the output:

`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gksu:
 gksu depends on libgksu2-0 (>= 2.0.8); however:
  Package libgksu2-0 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing package gksu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grive-tools:
 grive-tools depends on gksu; however:
  Package gksu is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package grive-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gksu
 grive-tools`

And running `dpkg -l 'libgksu2-0'`

`Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
rH  libgksu2-0     2.0.13~pre1- amd64        library providing su and sudo fun`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `lsb_release -a; uname -a; apt-cache policy libgksu2-0`

Comment: @A.B. I got Python 2.7.6

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg -l 'libgksu2-0'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair your Python installation, the missing module `_sysconfigdata_nd.py` is in `libpython2.7-minimal`:

```
apt-get download libpython2.7-minimal
sudo dpkg -i libpython2.7-minimal*
```

and install the (not) installed and half-configured thing

```
apt-get download libgksu2-0
sudo dpkg -i libgksu2-0*
```

Finally

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: I tried and got another error, I edited my post. Could you look at it please.

Comment: please check up the latest output.

Comment: Done from that. I did `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and I got this `Setting up gksu (2.0.2-6ubuntu2) ...`
`Setting up grive-tools (1.15) ...`

Comment: Yes. This is what I got

Comment: Now when I run `sudo apt-get -f install` I get the following: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 449 not upgraded.` Am I Done? Dependencies are solved?

Comment: Yes, the dependency problem is solved, run `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to install the available upgrades.